# Apex Test Class at 0 %

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

I have a apex trigger that I wrote a test class for but it is not hitting any code coverage and I do not know why. It should!

```
trigger DoNotTouchApprovedQuote on SBQQ__QuoteLine__c (before delete) {

    //If the Quote is approved, do not allow any deletions on the Quote lines.
    if(DoNotTouchApprovedQuoteHelper.IsItFirstRun == True){
    List<Id> quoteIds = new List<Id>();
    for (SBQQ__QuoteLine__c ql : trigger.old){
      quoteIds.add(ql.SBQQ__Quote__c);
    }

    List<SBQQ__Quote__c> quotes = [SELECT SBQQ__Status__c, Name FROM SBQQ__Quote__c WHERE ID IN :quoteIds];
    Map<Id, SBQQ__Quote__c> idToQuoteMap = new Map<Id, SBQQ__Quote__c>();
    for (SBQQ__Quote__c q : quotes){
      idToQuoteMap.put(q.Id,q);
    }

    for (SBQQ__QuoteLine__c ql : trigger.old){
      SBQQ__Quote__c q = idToQuoteMap.get(ql.SBQQ__Quote__c);
      if (q.SBQQ__Status__c != 'Draft' && q.SBQQ__Status__c != 'Rejected'){
        Trigger.oldMap.get(ql.Id).addError('You are trying to delete Quote Lines items on the Quote ' + q.name + ' but it is blocked because of Quote Status : ' + q.SBQQ__Status__c);
      }
    }
  }

  DoNotTouchApprovedQuoteHelper.IsItFirstRun = False;   
}
```

Test Class

```
@IsTest 
Public Class DoNotTouchApprovedQuote_Test {

    Static TestMethod Void DoNotTouchApprovedQuote() {

    DoNotTouchApprovedQuoteHelper.IsItFirstRun = True;

           //CREATE PARENT BUSINESS ACCOUNT
    Account AccountBusiness = new Account
    (
        Name = 'Business Account', 
        RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Business Account').getRecordTypeId()
    );

    Insert AccountBusiness;

    //CREATE CHILD LAB ACCOUNT
    Account AccountLabs = new Account
    (
        Name = 'Labs Account', 
        RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Labs Account').getRecordTypeId(), 
        ParentId = AccountBusiness.ID
    );

    Insert AccountLabs; 

    Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

     //Create a Product
    Product2 ProductStandAlone = new Product2
    (
        Name = 'Sample Product', 
        Model_Name__c = 'Test Model',
        Product_Type__c = 'StandAlone',
        Compatibility_Check__c = 'Y',
        Model__c = '994.20P.2',
        Brand__c = 'Test Brand 1'
    );

     Insert ProductStandAlone;

     Opportunity opportunity = new Opportunity
     (
         name = 'Sample Opportunity',
         location__c = AccountLabs.id,
         stageName = 'Negotiation',
         closeDate = Date.today()
     );

    insert opportunity;


       SBQQ__Quote__c Quote = new SBQQ__Quote__c
       (
           SBQQ__Opportunity2__c = opportunity.id,
           SBQQ__Account__c = AccountLabs.id,
           COT_Number__c = '1234',
           SBQQ__Primary__c = True,
           SBQQ__Status__c = 'Approved'

       );

    insert Quote;

    SBQQ__QuoteLine__c QuoteLine = new SBQQ__QuoteLine__c
        (
            SBQQ__Quote__c = Quote.Id,
            SBQQ__Product__c = ProductStandAlone.Id
        );

    insert QuoteLine;

    test.startTest();

    delete QuoteLine;

    test.stopTest(); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running all tests from Developer Console to see a refresh status of code coverage?

Comment: I will try it now I suppose. Not sure why that what handle it though

Comment: Yep tried and nothing

Comment: Does the test pass? When you look at the code coverage view (line-by-line highlights) in the source file, what do you see? If you place a `System.debug()` in your trigger, do you see it in the logs? Is the trigger active?

Comment: Ugh ------- That is correct. The trigger is not active. why in the world would i have an inactive trigger in prod.

Comment: Expanded my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of things to look at here to determine why the test coverage isn't being generated:

1. Does the test pass?
2. When you look at the code coverage view (line-by-line highlights) in the source file, what do you see? In many cases, you'll see indications that the test data isn't correct for the code under test, which manifests as coverage extending only up to the beginning of a conditional block or loop.
3. If you place a `System.debug()` in your trigger, do you see it in the logs?
4. Is the trigger active?

In this case, the trigger being deactivated was causing the issue, per comments.